# How to user a simple list with a collection view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a List object called mylist that contains a list of strings that represent names stored in a database. I want to display this list in a collection view. So far, i've been able to set the collection view itemsource property to mylist, which works fine. when i do this, it shows me the list in the default mode for collection view which is a vertical list. Now, i want to actually apply some formatting to the list by putting it inside of a grid and making it look nice. This is where my issue is. All of the examples on microsoft documentation set the Binding of the collection view to some class, and then they set the binding for the views in the list to the properties of that class. The issue with that for me is that I am not using the MVVM architecture. I am not setting the binding to a class. I want to set it directly to a list object. This is what i have so far for my xaml

```
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />              
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                
                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Text=**WHAT DO I PUT HERE**
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Text=**WHAT DO I PUT HERE**
                        />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    ...
</CollectionView>
```

and from my code behind file here is the relevant snippet
```Collection.Itemsource = mylist;
```

As you can see, i want to display the data that is in my list string in the text of the labels i have created. but i don't know how to reference that data. I've already tried mylist[0] but that doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

if your `ItemSource` is a `List<string>`

```
Text=**WHAT DO I PUT HERE**
```

should be

```
Text="{Binding .}"
```

`.` tells it to use the value of the object itself, not a property of the object

Comment: Wow, this is super simple. Thank you! one more question if you don't mind. What if i end up changing my mind and instead of using a List<string> for mylist, i use an ObservableCollection<string> as the itemsource? would it still work the same? thank you